# How to test REST in spring app with spring security

Tags: spring, testing, rest, spring-security, jersey

I've got spring web application with jersey rest services. However rest is secured via spring security and login process is very hard to perform from unit test code. I'd like to test rest services with whole spring security disabled. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of annotation based web services is that you can unit-test them easily.

```
class WebServiceEndpoint {

    @Path("/foo/{fooId}")
    @POST
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response doFoo(@PathParam("fooId") Integer fooId) { 
        /// ... web service endpoint implementation
    }

}
```

If you're using Spring's servlet filter for security, then there shouldn't be any security-related code in the `doFoo` method, so you can just create a new `WebServiceEndpoint` class and call the method. So that's one way of 'disabling' security.

When you say the login process is 'hard', what do you mean? If you've succeeded in logging in once, then you can just reuse the same code in your other unit tests (e.g. in a `@Before` method).

Answer (score 0):

Just test it as a pojo. Pass in whatever, return whatever, don't load an app context at all - that would be an integration test.

The ability to easily test functionality without the framework loaded is one of the key advantages of spring.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what's "hard," so I'm assuming that you've got something in your REST service, i.e. in the java method that you want to test, which requires authentication results. Spring has utilities for mocking the authentication results. For example, you can do the following in a `@Before` setup method:

```
Object principal = null; // fix this
Object credentials = null; // fix this
Authentication auth = new org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationToken(principal, credentials);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

But again, you haven't said what problem you're actually trying to solve...